# Infimum of $\left\{\frac{n}{n^2+1}\:\:;\:n\:\in \mathbb N\right\}$ with a proof

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Consider $A=\left\{\frac{n}{n^2+1}\:\:;\:n\:\in \:N\right\}$.  I need to find and prove $\inf(A)$.

So I know that I need to prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$ exists some $a\:\in A$ such that $a\:=\:\frac{n_0}{n_0^2\:+1}$ for some $n_0$, so  $\inf(A)\:+\:\epsilon \:>\:a$

What is the method? How to choose what $\epsilon$ is bigger than?

Comment: The conclusion isn't true though. If $n=100$ then $100/10001<1/2$. Perhaps you meant supremum?

Comment: @SuzuHirose tnx! i edit now the question if you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised to match corrected question and the OP’s background.**

Let $a_n=\dfrac{n}{n^2+1}$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2+1}-\frac{n}{n^2+1}&=\frac{n+1}{n^2+2n+2}-\frac{n}{n^2+1}\\\\
&=\frac{(n+1)(n^2+1)-n(n^2+2n+2)}{(n^2+1)(n^2+2n+2)}\\\\
&=\frac{n^3+n^2+n+1-(n^3+2n^2+2n)}{(n^2+1)(n^2+2n+2)}\\\\
&=\frac{-n^2-n+1}{(n^2+1)(n^2+2n+2)}\;.
\end{align*}$$

The denominator is always positive, so this is negative when the numerator is negative, i.e., when $-n^2-n+1<0$. This occurs when $n^2+n>1$, i.e., when $n(n+1)>1$, and this is clearly true for every positive integer $n$. Thus, we know that $a_1>a_2>a_3>\ldots\;$.

How small can these fractions get? For every positive integer $n$ we have

$$0<a_n=\frac{n}{n^2+1}<\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac1n\;.\tag{1}$$

Thus, $a_n$ is always bigger than $0$, but by taking $n$ big enough, we can get it as close to $0$ as we want. That says that $\inf A$ ought to be $0$. Now you just have to show that if $\epsilon>0$, there is an $n$ such that $a_n<\epsilon$. The inequality $(1)$ should help you do that.

Comment: yeah i copletely wrong, look for the edit question tnx!

Comment: @nad: I’ve rewritten the answer completely to match the edited question.

Comment: well tnx, but i not yeat learned limit so its completley chinese for me hhh..all i have is the definition of infimum for sets

Comment: @nad: Does that mean that you also haven’t yet learned about the derivative?

Comment: correct..just in the beginnigs of calculus 1..

Comment: @nad: Okay; let me think a bit about how I might give a more suitable explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac{n}{n^2 + 1} \geq 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N},$ inf$A \geq 0.$

Claim: inf$A = 0.$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be any real. By Archimedean property, there exist $n \in \mathbb{N},$ such that $\frac{1}{\epsilon} < n.$ So $\frac{1}{\epsilon} < m + \frac{1}{m} = \frac{m^2 + 1}{m}, \forall m \geq n \Rightarrow \frac{m}{m^2 + 1} < \epsilon, \forall m \geq n.$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're correct. Let $n = 2$. Then $\frac{n}{n^{2} + 1} = \frac{2}{5} = 0.4 < 0.5$. Indeed, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n^{2} + 1} = 0$, so in fact for all but finitely many $n$, we have $\frac{n}{n^{2} + 1} < \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: tnx i edit now !!

Comment: If you want $\sup A = \frac{1}{2}$, and in fact $\max A = \frac{1}{2}$, then we can use Brian's suggestion: $\frac{1}{2} \geq \frac{n}{n^{2} + 1} \iff n^{2} + 1 \geq 2n$, which is easy to show, e.g. by induction.

Comment: tnx but i need the inf..

Comment: $\inf A = 0$. You can determine it by the monotone convergence theorem for sequences. Monotonicity shouldn't be difficult to show.